# how to use basic-authentication access jira rest api when SSO is configured？

Tags: jira-rest-api

JIRA instance is configured to login with SSO, but some client only support base-auth(username and password) ,  So How can i call jira api use Base Authentication when login meth is SSO.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a native user account directly in Jira instead of using an account from the SSO (and you can simply use Basic authentication).

Comment: Thanks metheriault. another question , i have been trying to access api like http://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/search?oa_AuthType=base , and set user account directly in jira in header, but there is no return.

Comment: You must search for something (jql parameter):
`https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=fred&os_AuthType=basic`.